# specifying different retry limit and retry delay for different jobs in backburner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using beaneater/beanstalk in my app for maintaining the job queues.
https://github.com/nesquena/backburner

My global config file for backburner look like -

```
Backburner.configure do |config|
  config.beanstalk_url    = ["beanstalk://#{CONFIG['beanstalk']['host']}:#{CONFIG['beanstalk']['port']}"]
  config.tube_namespace   = CONFIG['beanstalk']['tube_name']
  config.on_error         = lambda { |e| puts e }
  config.max_job_retries  = 5 # default 0 retries
  config.retry_delay      = 30 # default 5 seconds
  config.default_priority = 65536
  config.respond_timeout  = 120
  config.default_worker   = Backburner::Workers::Simple
  config.logger           = Logger.new('log/backburner.log')
  config.priority_labels  = { :custom => 50, :useless => 1000 }
  config.reserve_timeout  = nil
end
```

I want to set different retry limit and retry delay for different jobs.
I was looking at rubydoc for corresponding variable/function. [As per this rubydoc link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/nesquena/backburner/master/Backburner/Queue/ClassMethods), I tried configuring retry_limit locally in a worker as:

One specific worker look like -

```
class AbcJob
  include Backburner::Queue
  queue "abc_job"  # defaults to 'backburner-jobs' tube
  queue_priority 10 # most urgent priority is 0
  queue_respond_timeout 300 # number of seconds before job times out
  queue_retry_limit 2

  def self.perform(abc_id)
    .....Task to be done.....
  end
end
```

However, it is still picking up the retry limit from global config file and retrying it 5 times instead of 2. Any thing that I am missing here?

How can I over write retry limit and retry delay locally?

Comment: Are you using the ThreadsOnFork worker? The docs say it's only supported with that worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find right way to do it but I found a solution.
I am putting entire body of `perform` in begin-rescue block and in case of failure I am re-enqueing it with custom delay. Also, to keep the track of number of retries I made it an argument which I am enqueueing.

```
class AbcJob
include Backburner::Queue
queue "abc_job"  # defaults to 'backburner-jobs' tube
queue_priority 10 # most urgent priority is 0
queue_respond_timeout 300 # number of seconds before job times out

def self.perform(abc_id, attempt = 1)
  begin
    .....Task to be done.....
  rescue StandardError => e
    # Any notification method so that you can know about failure reason and fix it before next retry
    # I am using NotificationMailer with e.message as body to debug
    # Any function you want your retry delay to be, I am using quadratic
    delay = attempt * attempt
    if attempt + 1 < GlobalConstant::MaxRetryCount
      Backburner::Worker.enqueue(AbcJob, [abc_id, attempt + 1], delay: delay.minute)
    else
      raise # if you want your jobs to be buried eventually
    end
  end
end
```

I have kept the default value of attempt to 1 so that magic nuber `1` do not appear in code which might raise question about why are we passing a constant. For enqueueing from other places in code you can use simple enqueue

```
Backburner::Worker.enqueue(AbcJob, abc_id)
```